# Kernel offset disabled, kernel panic not syncing

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am having VMware workstation 11 installed on windows 10 LTSB 16 and my virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04) didn't open and I get the following error message
[kernel offset disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWA1d.png)

and when I tried to log in using the old kernel I am stuck by the next figure
[initramfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utS1I.png)

and when I tried to make a new VM using a different ubuntu iso same kernel error is received any help, please

Comment: For the "old kernel" does this https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck maybe contain useful directions?

Comment: thank you so much it works i really appreciate your answer

Comment: I am glad it did!